# displaying Database information on a chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, charts

I am trying to make a LINQ query on an existing database, get a particular column and display all data on that column on a chart.

But I do not get any display. If I hard code the data in the list for the chart, I get the display. Issue seems to be with deriving data using the LINQ query and how I am storing it.

I am looking for the chart to look like this:

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZWGG.jpg)

I am using ASP.NET MVC and trying to make the query and setup the chart at the controller and call the output as an image at the view page. My code is as follows:

Controller (GroceryController):

```
FruitContext db = new FruitContext();
public ActionResult GetChart()
{
    List<string> xChartList = new List<string>();

    var xChartData = from x in db.Fruits
                     select x.FruitName;

    foreach(var x in xChartData)
    {
        xChartList.Add(x);
    }
    //xChartData.ToList(); //Doesn't display either

    var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddSeries(
            chartType: "bar",
            legend: "Fruits",
            xValue: xChartList, //If I hard code this, it works for example as new[] { "Apples", "Grapes", "Oranges", "Mangos", "Peaches" })
            yValues: new[] { "100", "200", "300", "400", "500" })
        .Write();

    return null;
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="/Grocery/GetChart" />
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any data back in xChartData ?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout No data. The image doesn't show.

Comment: Don't worry about the image ... debug it and see if your getting any data back from your linq query

Comment: @MicahArmantrout Ran a debug and looped over xChartList. It holds the data Apples and Oranges as expected.

Comment: Why are you using that `foreach` loop? Why don't you just use `xChartData` instead of `xChartList`?  If `xChartList` has the data, then it means you're doing something wrong. Maybe your code is not exactly the same as the code you've posted here?

Comment: @ataravati I've double checked. The code is exactly the same. I have tried with both xChartList and xChartData and the result is the same.

Comment: And you say `xChartData` holds the data as expected. That doesn't make any sense.